# sending jsonobject to server

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i am trying to send the `Jsonobject request` to the server and  i am getting a reply  of `volley timeouterror`

I read something on volley `RetryPolicy`, that i should increase the time limit  of my request and till getting the same error. please guys help to look through my code, and assist me with the right request.

Thanks in advance

```js
 private void getpay() {

            prgDialog.show();
            final  String amount = Fund_amount;
            final String number = Card.getText().toString().trim();
            final String year = Year.getText().toString().trim();
            final String month = Month.getText().toString().trim();
            final String cvv = CVV.getText().toString().trim();
            final String pin = Pin.getText().toString().trim();
            aaaaaa


            JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://api.myflex.ng/wallet/fund",
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                prgDialog.cancel();

                                String  data = response.getString("status");


                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("data");


                                JSONObject transfer = obj.getJSONObject("transfer");

                                Payment_massage = transfer.getString("flutterChargeResponseMessage");
                                Payment_ref = transfer.getString("flutterChargeReference");


                                if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                                    prgDialog.cancel();
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                                    builder.setTitle("myFlex");
                                    builder.setMessage("Connection Error. Please check Your Network Connection");
                                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                                    builder.show();

                                } else {
                                    prgDialog.cancel();

                                    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    trans.replace(R.id.change_transfer, new card_token());
                                    trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                    trans.addToBackStack(null);
                                    trans.commit();


                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    },

                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            prgDialog.cancel();

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                            builder.setTitle("myFlex");
                            builder.setCancelable(false);
                            builder.setMessage("Connection Error. Please check Your Internet Connection ");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                            builder.show();
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Authorization", User_Token);
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");  
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json";
                }


               @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("amount", amount);
                        jsonObject.put("card", come());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("Volley", "Error" + String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                    return jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
                }

                private JSONObject come() throws JSONException {
                    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        params.put("number", number);
                        params.put("expiry_month", month);
                        params.put("expiry_year", year);
                        params.put("cvv", cvv);
                        params.put("pin", pin);
                        Log.i("Volley", "Error" + String.valueOf(params));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error" + params);
                    }

                    return params;
                }

            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            obreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(100 * 1000, 0,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(obreq);
        }
```

Comment: why don't use  volley

Comment: What can I use, please give me option and show me how to do it

Comment: did you tried in postman?

Comment: Yes it working fine on postman

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure retry policy. Give a large timeout and try

```
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req"; 

obreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
requestQueue.addToRequestQueue(obreq, tag_json_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeout in `Volley` is represented in milliseconds. Default time out is 25000 milliseconds or 25 seconds.

```
int timeOut = 120; // 2 min
int timeOutInMillis = timeOut * 1000;
obreq .setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(timeOutInMillis,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

requestQueue.add(obreq);
```

For more details:[Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. add volley library to build.gradle

   ```
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
   ```
2. You can call like bellow using volley

   ```
     private void doLoginAction() {


      String url_login = "http://10.0.2.2/test_sstem/public/login";


   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
       new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               //pDialog.dismiss();


               try {
                   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                   JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ParentNode");
                   for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                       String key1 = jo.getString("key1");
                       String key2 = jo.getString("key2");



                   }
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }


           }
       },
       new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

               try {

                   if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {
                       //Time out error

                   }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                       //net work error

                   } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                       //error

                   } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                       //Erroor
                   } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                       //Error

                   } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                      //Error

                   }else{
                       //Error
                   }
                   //End


               } catch (Exception e) {


               }

           }
       }) {
     @Override
     protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
         params.put("uname", "era@gmail.com");
         params.put("pass", "123456");



          return params;
      }

   };

      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
     }
   ```

Comment: You can submit easily to post your request & get response quickly